# Create a copy of a dataframe from selected rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, copy

I am trying to create a new dataframe from selected rows of another dataframe

```
TestData = pd.read_csv('Aptitude_Classification_data.csv')
TeamC = ['Synonyms and Antonyms', 'Time and Work', 'Permutations and Combinations', 'LCM and HCF', 'Profit and Loss']
SelectedData = pd.DataFrame(TestData[TestData['Sub-Category'].isin(TeamC)])
pd.unique(SelectedData['Sub-Category'])
SelectedData.head()
```

Code and output:

[image]

I want the new dataframe as a copy with all the data and index starting from 1 and without any breaks

Comment: `SelectedData=SelectedData.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         TestData2 = TestData.loc[(TestData['Sub-Category']=='Synonyms and Antonyms')|
         (TestData['Sub-Category']=='Time and Work') |
         (TestData['Sub-Category']=='Permutations and Combinations') |
         (TestData['Sub-Category']=='LCM and HCF') |
         (TestData['Sub-Category']=='Profit and Loss)
        ].reset_index(drop=True)
```